# getIn() vs getMessage() of an Exchange in apache.camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I try to understand the difference between getIn() and getMessage() of the apache.camel Exchange. In documentation it says that getIn() returns the inbound message, while getMessage() returns current message. My question is: when inbound message is not altered in the current Processor, does getIn() and getMessage() return the same message?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If using [InOnly MEP](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html), methods `getIn()` and `getMessage()` returns the same instance of `Message`.

The logic of `getMesage()` is simple. If exchange have associated `out` message, return `out`. Otherwise return `in`.

In most cases there will be no `out` message associated with `Exchange`. In Apache Camel 3 is `getOut()` deprecated, reserved for edge cases and internal use for component developers. End users are encouraged to prefer `getMessage()` instead of `getIn()` and `getOut()`.

Comment: "encouraged to prefer `getMessage()` instead of `getIn()` and `getOut()` " -> 

Regarding the `getIn()` part: I cannot find such an encouragement for the `getIn()` method. Neither in the [Exchange JavaDoc](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.apache.camel/camel-api/3.0.0/org/apache/camel/Exchange.html) nor in the [documentation of the MEP](https://camel.apache.org/manual/faq/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html). Where did you get this information from?

Answer (score 2):

`Exchange.getIn()` will contain the initial message for the route (eg the message created by a `Consumer`) whereas `Exchange.getMessage()` will change over time as the message is transformed.

`Exchange.getOut()`, `Exchange.setOut(...)` and `Exchange.hasOut()` have been deprecated. Before they were deprecated we needed to write code such as

```java
Message message = exchange.hasOut() ? exchange.getOut() : exchange.getIn();
doStuff(message)
```

The "out" concept has been deprecated in favour of get/set "message" so we can now write code like

```java
Message message = exchange.getMessage();
doStuff(message)
```

If you look at [AbstractExchange.java](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/007c4b6f7c054a01cf1426ea4ed32c7c0339ba71/core/camel-support/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/support/AbstractExchange.java#L560-L563) you can see `getMessage()` is calling the old deprecated methods

```java
class AbstractExchange implements ExtendedExchange {
    ...
    @Override
    public Message getMessage() {
        return hasOut() ? getOut() : getIn();
    }
    ...
}
```